# How to get .net web api in jsonP, although it returns json data by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on .net web api in Asp.net Mvc5 project...

By default it returns xml or json...in my project json/xml data returning fine...

I am looking for the setting so that i can get response in JSONP....

> Web Api config :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "SmallBizApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
 config.Formatters.Clear();
        // config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
       // config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()));
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
       // config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

I am new to webapi's and looking for a way to do this please help....
Thanks for your time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

with

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

i did this on a recent project. and it worked just fine.